# How to control the sensitivity of accelerometer sensor Programmatically?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I want to use the accelerometer sensor in my android application.
my question: how to can control the sensitivity of accelerometer sensor Programmatically?

Comment: youcan try this link https://github.com/reesebutler/Android-accelerometer-and-touch-screen-control

Answer (score 0):

You can not - android API does not provides means to do this

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a low pass or high pass filter on the data.  A low pass filter will be sensitive to large, slow movements, such as device rotation, while a high pass filter will ignore that data and detect quick movements like flicks.

I don't have the implementation details here, but you should be able to find something either on stack overflow or wikipedia, or perhaps somebody else has the details.